# AngularJS IF Directive use columns

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a if directive (it works well).

When I click on the **NAME** , it shows the **image**.

But I would like the image in an other column:

```
    <!-- COLUMN 1 -->
    <div class="col-md-4">
       <div ng-repeat="product in products">
          <h3><a style="cursor: pointer;" ng-click="products.chosen = product">name: {{product.name}}</a>   </h3>
          <!-- add image to colum 2 -->
          <img ng-if="products.chosen == product" ng-src="{{product.url_image}}"/>
       </div>
    </div>

<!-- IMAGES COLUMN 2-->
<div class="col-md-4">
   <!-- this doesn't work -->
   <img ng-if="products.chosen == product" ng-src="{{product.url_image}}"/>
</div>
```

HERE IS THE MOCKUP:

http://hpics.li/7678189

When I click on the name, I have a picture that appears just right down.
I would like the image displayed in Column2.

Thanks for your help !

Carlos

Comment: Hey Carlos, can u put some screen shot of how you expect it?

Comment: You want all the chosen images in columns 2?

Comment: Yes, the image selected in column 2. Just added the mockup. Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to display all selected images in column 2, or only one at once?\

Comment: Fixed the problem. Thanks for your help anyway !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function testController($scope)
{
  $scope.products = [{name: "prod 1", url_image: "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/514-t6qvDYL._SL150_.jpg"},{name: "prod 2", url_image: "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41Bz5RkS3OL._SS120_RO10,1,201,225,243,255,255,255,15_.jpg"},{name: "prod 3", url_image: "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41alFkSKj2L._SS120_RO10,1,201,225,243,255,255,255,15_.jpg"}];
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="" ng-controller="testController">
<!-- COLUMN 1 -->
    <div class="col-md-4">
       <div ng-repeat="product in products">
          <h3><a style="cursor: pointer;" ng-click="products.chosen = product">name: {{product.name}}</a>   </h3>
       </div>
    </div>

<!-- IMAGES COLUMN 2-->
<div class="col-md-4">
   <img ng-if="products.chosen" ng-src="{{products.chosen.url_image}}"/>
</div>
</div>
```